# Why does the USDC transferWithAuthorisation method work inconsistently?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

The USDC smart contract on Ethereum has a transferWithAuthorisation that any address can call if they have a signature.

However, the method seems to be inconsistent and often fails.

What is the reason for this?

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48?method=0xe3ee160e

Most of the failures are due to: "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted] "

Answer (score 1):

I debugged some of the failing transactions with [Tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0xd3d52f26d231709d3e2bd5df6f6d6908f1b6ac3cf70abe6746229938114c728c/debugger?trace=0.2.0.0.2.0) and learned that they all (or at least those that I debugged) fail on insufficient gas limit.

Each EVM operation costs some predefined amount of gas units. The transaction sender specifies gas limit, and then buys this amount (times gas price) for ETH. If the transaction consumes less gas units than the limit, the difference is refunded.

The `transferWithAuthorisation()` function seems to cost between 72k and 82k gas units depending on internal code logic (successful transactions: [0x7e...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7ea5e6377ff878fd55d3d7e82fb2123fd97dc5dd85683eac3ff172b33f955086), [0x32...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x324de7e0bc23e37e7aaa5adde73227af9a1ce6bb73c70ed53e527eeceff8ba9d), [0xec...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xec69931fe7cc927f62b7c6d6141d5c002e3e91ab1c8b8f3e26a0075a626eef5a)).

However the failing transactions supplied lower gas limit between 59k and 62k ([0xd3...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd3d52f26d231709d3e2bd5df6f6d6908f1b6ac3cf70abe6746229938114c728c), [0xf1...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf11de395e1f430c083ec84f40e124e70d4ea1459da266f819576e2cfd4326ac9), [0x54...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54695c0c02cfa6707a77416a543f06bbf367688d42766270cdda62a3eb926b88)).

So the sender possibly used an incorrect estimation of gas usage, and specified an insufficient limit.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this was really helpful. And I'll be sure to use Tenderly in future. Thanks Petr 